# Deadlock at freeing thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, deadlock

Having some problem freeing up a worker thread, i just dont see why is the deadlock at freeing the thread in the thread's OnTerminate event handler `(TMaster.slvsrch_termination)`.
Im using postmessage instead of synchronize in thread execute to sync some VCL control, just to avoid deadlock.

```
procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.Execute;
var    
  activesearch: integer;
begin
  activesearch := 1;
  FMaster.CMD_SEARCH;               
  FSW.Start;
  while not terminated do begin
    postmessage( FDevTree_HWND, WM_STOPPER_REFRESH, trunc(Fsw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000), integer(FMasterNode) );    
    //
    if (SimpleEvent.WaitFor( SEARCH_DELAY_SEC ) <> wrTimeOut) or (activesearch <> 1) then break;  
    activesearch := Fmaster.CMD_LISTCNT;  
    FSW.Stop;
  end;
end;

procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.DoTerminate;
begin
  inherited;      
  self.simpleEvent.SetEvent; 
end;
```

FreeOnTerminate property of the thread been set to false:

```
...
Fslave_search_thread: Tsrch_slave_thread; 
...
Fslave_search_thread.FreeOnTerminate := false
Fslave_search_thread.OnTerminate := slvsrch_termination;
...

procedure TMaster.slvsrch_termination(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  if Assigned(Fslave_search_thread) then
  begin
    Fslave_search_thread.free; //Deadlock, why?
    Fslave_search_thread := nil;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deadlock occurs because the thread's destructor waits on the thread. It calls `WaitFor` to do so. The thread's destructor is called from `slvsrch_termination`. That is the `OnTerminate` event handler for the thread. And `OnTerminate` event handlers are executed in the main thread because they are invoked with a call to `Synchronize`.

And here's the dead lock. It progresses like this:

1. Thread `Execute` completes and the thread runs its termination code.
2. Thread termination code is synchronized onto the main thread. At this point the slave thread is waiting for the main thread via the call to `Synchronize`.
3. Thread termination code, running on the main thread, destroys the slave thread. This leads to a `WaitFor` on the thread. Now the main thread is waiting on the slave thread.

Steps 2 and 3 are your deadlock.

---

Beyond the deadlock, it is also an error that you free the slave thread instance from its own `OnTerminate` handler. Look at the code in the thread procedure:

```
FreeThread := Thread.FFreeOnTerminate;
Thread.DoTerminate;
Thread.FFinished := True;
```

Your `OnTerminate` handler is invoked from the call to `DoTerminate`. When it returns, `Thread` has been destroyed, but the code still access it. What's more look at this code of yours:

```
procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.DoTerminate;
begin
  inherited;      
  self.simpleEvent.SetEvent; 
end;
```

The `inherited` invokes the `OnTerminate` handler. That frees the instance. Then you access the instance.

The bottom line is that you must not free the thread from its `OnTerminate` handler.

Comment: Weird... I got the orange "A new answer has been posted..." bar literally as I was hitting the answer button but your answer showed up with a timestamp ten minutes earlier than mine.  Your magic powers never cease to amaze, David!

Comment: But he is not trying to free the thread from OnTerminate handler of same thread. As i understand it is 2 different threads and he is freeing slave thread from OnTerminate event of master thread. Did i miss something?

Comment: @J... I deleted the original version of the answer when I had doubts. I wondered if the erroneous call to `Free` causes the deadlock. I think not though, although it is clearly wrong. I think the deadlock is on the event.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn `Fslave_search_thread.free` is called in `TMaster.slvsrch_termination`. That handler is attached to the `Fslave_search_thread.OnTerminate` event. The fact that it is a method of `TMaster` does not change the fact that it fires on the termination of the slave thread.

Comment: @David. Ok, you right. I supposed that slvsrch_termination assigned to master thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: although you are correct that `Free()` cannot safely be called in the `OnTerminate` handler, *nothing* in your answer actually addresses the question asked. The real answer is that the code deadlocks because the `TThread` destructor calls `WaitFor()` on itself if the thread is still running, the thread is still running when `OnTerminate` is called, and `OnTerminate` is called by `Synchronize()`. So the main thread and the worker thread are waiting on each other - deadlock occurs. The rest of your answer, although technically accurate, is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Remy You are correct. I misdiagnosed it as a deadlock on the event. But the `Execute` method has clearly returned because `slvsrch_termination` is executing. I will fix this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `Execute()` exited, but the inherited `DoTerminate()` did not, and `DoTerminate()` runs in the same thread context as `Execute()`.

Comment: Ok so the VCL thread is waiting for the worker thread to finish (.waitfor in .free method) but cannot because the worker thread waiting for vcl thread to came back from synchronize? Btw, exactly where the .onterminate flag been set by the thread itself, if i dont set it manually? In .DoTerminate?

Comment: You mean the `Terminated` flag? If you don't call `Terminate` then I presume that you set `activesearch` to be a value other than 1. I do wonder why you use an integer for what appears to be a boolean.

Comment: @Tdiop: yes, that is why it deadlocks. There is no `OnTerminate` flag, are you referring to the `Terminated` property? It is only set by calling `Terminate()`. If you don't call that yourself, the only place `TThread` calls it on itself is in its destructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't say it before, but thank you for correcting me. I do appreciate that.

Comment: Yes i was referring to the terminated flag. Thanks to both of You. I dont really know why i use integer instead of boolean, maybe i was planning more values for the result of LISTCND.